# Get column and row indices from absolute position

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

In a multi-line `EditText`, how can I get column and row indices from an absolute position obtained via `getSelectionStart()`?

Manually calculating the column and row indices from the string returned by `getText()` won't work because `EditText` does automatic wordwrapping so there is no way to tell when words are wrapped, i.e. when the row index has to be incremented and the column index has to be reset.

So is it possible at all to calculate the column and row indices from an absolute index obtained via `getSelectionStart()`?